# Graph Theory-Eulerian Path?

Tags: graph-theory

In a certain country, $40$ roads lead out of each city. When all roads are open, it is possible to travel from any city to any other. Each road leads from one city to another; there are no dead end roads.

If one road is closed for repairs, is it still necessarily possible to travel from any city to any other? Prove your answer.

---

How can I use graph theory? Is this a Eulerian Path Question?

Answer (score 3):

Think of each city as a vertex and each road as an edge. The degree of each vertex is $40$, and the graph is connected. Now you remove one edge. There are no loops (each road leads from one city to *another*), so you now have two vertices of degree $39$, the rest all being still of degree $40$. You want to show that the graph is still connected.

HINT: Each component must contain an even number of vertices of odd degree.